# Finding the total sum of salary for person who worked at least two years

Tags: sql-server

Employee table

[image]

So, I am looking for a result with Name, salary and age - Salary should be the sum of all he earned, also it should be calculated only for person who has worked more than a year

For Example employee Sunny worked totally 4 years whereas Arpita worked only one year

I tried group by name and calculated totally earning but not able to find only for person who worked for more than a year, I mean at least two years

select name as [Name of Employee], sum(salary) as [Salary Earned] from Employee group by name;

Comment: [Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: In future could you please avoid [screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530) and provide your table structures as DDL and your data as DML? p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT name AS [Name of Employee], 
    SUM(salary) AS [Salary Earned] 
FROM Employee 
GROUP BY name
HAVING MAX(year) > 1;
```

This will exclude those records whose maximum "year" having is 1, basically those who have not been employed for more than 1 year.